# File not copying to stream when deployed in Azure, yet working through VS emulator

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure

My program takes a MP4 file uploads it to a blob then trims it down to 10 seconds and re-uploads it to the blob. I currently have this working when running it through the azure emulator in VS however, when I deploy it to the cloud the output files have 0 bytes.

Trimmer:

```
public static void Trimmer(string localStoragePath, Stream output )
{
    string path2= localStoragePath.Remove(localStoragePath.Length-4 )+ "_trimmed.mp4";
    string ffmpeg = "ffmpeg.exe";
    bool success = false;
    string ExeArguments;

    try
    {

        Process proc;
        proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = ffmpeg;
        ExeArguments = @" -t 10 -i " + localStoragePath + " -map_metadata 0 -acodec copy " 
                                     + path2 + " -y";
        //ExeArguments = @"–t 10 -i -acodec" + localStoragePath + path2 ;
        Trace.TraceInformation(ExeArguments);
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = ExeArguments;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        success = true;
    }

    catch { }

    Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format("Video has been trimmed") );

    using (Stream file = File.OpenRead(path2))
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format("Video moving to CopyStream"));
        copyStream(file, output);
    }
}
```

Copy Stream:

```
public static void copyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format("Video has been trimmed and now sent to be copied to stream"));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
}
```

Blob mover:

```
public static void fileMover (CloudBlob mover, string filePath, Stream input, Stream output)
        {


            string localStoragePath;
            //start string from 7th letter, eg, images
            string link = filePath.Substring(7);


                LocalResource locRes;
                locRes = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("WorkerRoleLocalStorage");

                //To determine the path to the local storage resource's directory

                localStoragePath = string.Format(locRes.RootPath);

            //Moving file to local storage
            try
            {
                mover.DownloadToFile(localStoragePath + link, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                Trace.TraceInformation("file mover has been called " + localStoragePath + link);
                //add meta data
            }
            catch(Exception e) { }

            try
            {
                Trimmer(localStoragePath + link, output);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {}
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you add the parts where you open the blob for reading/writing?

Comment: @juunas Added to the main post.

Comment: I suggest you add some logging in your empty catch blocks, as you are throwing away helpful information from any exceptions that may occur.

Comment: @stuartd I agree, however, no exception is being thrown, and the program is working while under and emulator. The error's only apply when it is deployed to the cloud.

Comment: That's my point - how can you know no exceptions are thrown when deployed?

Comment: Have you found the cause and solve this issue, any updates?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I have created my project to test this issue. I could make it work as expected both on my side with storage Emulator and deployed to Azure with real storage account.

[image]

I noticed that you have wrapped your code with `try-catch`, here are some suggestions for you to locate and solve this issue:

- You could enable diagnostics for your cloud service project to log your application logs before deploying to Azure. You could leverage `System.Diagnostics.Trace` to log the detailed error when you capturing the exception. For more details, you could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-diagnostics-for-cloud-services-and-virtual-machines#enable-diagnostics-in-cloud-service-projects-before-deploying-them).
- For `Trimmer` method, you need to trouble check the `path2` file is exist. I have tested that if the file is not generated, then your output blob file would be 0 in size. I modified the `Trimmer` method, you could refer to it.

```html
public static void Trimmer(string localStoragePath, CloudBlockBlob outPutBlob)
{
    string path2 = localStoragePath.Remove(localStoragePath.Length - 4) + "_trimmed.mp4";
    string ffmpeg = "ffmpeg.exe";
    bool success = false;
    string ExeArguments;
    try
    {
        Process proc;
        proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = ffmpeg;
        ExeArguments = @" -t 10 -i " + localStoragePath + " -map_metadata 0 -acodec copy "
                                        + path2 + " -y";
        Trace.TraceInformation(ExeArguments);
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = ExeArguments;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.TraceError($"Trimmer exception:{ex.Message}\r\nStackTrace:{ex.StackTrace}");
    }

    var fi = new FileInfo(path2);
    if (fi.Exists)
    {
        success = true;
        Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format("Video has been trimmed"));
        using (Stream file = File.OpenRead(path2))
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format("Video moving to CopyStream"));
            Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format("Video has been trimmed and now sent to be copied to stream"));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
            int len;
            using (Stream outpuStream = outPutBlob.OpenWrite())
            {
                while ((len = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    outpuStream.Write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
            }    
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Trace.TraceWarning(string.Format("Video has not been trimmed"));
    }
}
```

Additionally, you could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-diagnostics-for-cloud-services-and-virtual-machines#view-the-diagnostics-data) to view the diagnostics data or you could leverage [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) to check the `WADLogsTable` of your related storage account to check your application logs.